# attr_accessor variable nil when doing before_validation callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a before_validation as follows:

event.rb

```
attr_accessor :start_date
attr_accessible :start_time #recorded in database as a datetime

before_validation :build_start_time

...

def build_start_time
  begin
    self.start_time = DateTime.parse(start_date)
  rescue
      errors.add(:start_date, "invalid date")
      return false
  end
end
```

and the controller looks like:

```
def create
  @event = events.build(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    # some other method calls
    redirect_to @event
  else
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

start_date is being set by a <%= f.text_field :start_date %> call in a form view, and when I check the params it is being passed to the 'Create' method of the model controller correctly, but in the build_start_time method it is nil, so self.start_time is not being set. Can you explain why it would be nil and what the solution would be? I also tried referring to it as self.start_date but that didn't make a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making `start_date` also accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Either you call `attr_accessible` with `start_date` so `build()` can actually set it, or you can change your controller to:

```
def create
  @event = events.build(params[:event])
  @event.start_date = params[:event][:start_date]
  if @event.save
    # some other method calls
    redirect_to @event
  else
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

tente assim.

```
#app/models/adm/video.rb
class Adm::Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :titulo, :url_codigo, presence: true
  before_validation(on: [ :create, :update ]) do
    self.url_codigo = parse_youtube(url_codigo) #url_codigo = params[:adm_video][:url_codigo]
  end

  private
  #  pega só o codigo do link youtube para inserir no banco 
  def parse_youtube(url)
   if !url.blank?
     regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/
     return url.match(regex)[1] # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX_rKHnKJSg = iX_rKHnKJSg
   end
 end

end
```

grava no banco de dados sò código do video = iX_rKHnKJSg = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX_rKHnKJSg = iX_rKHnKJSg.

records in the database sò code iX_rKHnKJSg video = # = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX_rKHnKJSg iX_rKHnKJSg

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. This may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) You may not realise it, but there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.